# A circle has radius sqrt(10)/2 and pass through A(1,1).A line y = 3x - 7 pass through the centre of the circle.Find the equation of the circle?

Tags: circles

Here is my attempt

h = 3k -7 ----(1)

(h-1)^2 + (k -1)^2 = 10/4

(h-1)^2 + (3h - 8)^2 = 10/4

This second one doesn't working.Is my approch wrong?

P.S: Sorry for the typo.Also I assumed the center is C(h,k)

Comment: $(h-1)^2 + (k -1)^2 = 10/4$ is an equation for a circle with center $(1,1)$, not that passes through $(1,1)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: here, $(k,h)$ is the centre of the circle. So I think that this part of the equation is correct (although perhaps the OP has $h$ and $k$ confused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the centre lies on the line $y=3x-7$ we can parameterise the centre to be the point $(t,3t-7)$. So the equation of the circle is given by
$$(x-t)^2+(y-3t+7)^2=\frac52$$
for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$. As the point $A(1,1)$ lies on the circle, the equation must hold for $x=y=1$ hence
$$(1-t)^2+(8-3t)^2=\frac52$$
This quadratic has a single repeated root namely
$$t=\frac52$$
Hence the equation of the circle is
$$\left(x-\frac52\right)^2+\left(y-\frac12\right)^2=\frac52$$

Comment: Why the sudden downvotes? I don't see anything wrong with this answer...

Comment: Your answer is perfect to me as well as the others.The thing is I still haven't learnt all the functionalities of this site yet.I wanted to approved all the answers and my respects to all of you for your help.Sorry for whatever mess I have done.

Comment: @Ghost No, I just meant that $2$ people disliked my answer for whatever reason and decided to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find the point a distance of $\sqrt{10}/2$ on the line we are given from the point we are given. 
$$(x-1)^2+(3x-8)^2=5/2$$
$$10x^2-50x+65=5/2$$
$$x^2-5x+6.25=0$$
The point is therefore
$$x=5/2$$
$$y=1/2$$
This is the only such point, since the equation only has one root, therefore it is the center of the circle. Thus the equation of the circle is
$$(x-5/2)^2+(y-1/2)^2=5/2$$